# How to set up ssh config file (~/.ssh/config) to recognise /etc/hosts host names?

Tags: ssh

I have added the following line (with a different IP) into the `/etc/hosts` file:

```
192.168.0.4      my_pc
```

Likewise the `~/.ssh/config` file has the following entry in it:

```
Host 192.168.0.*
IdentityFile ~/id_rsa
```

Sending a `ping` to `my_pc`, sends a ping to `192.168.0.4` as intended. I can also ssh into the machine using `ssh user@192.168.0.4`. If I try `ssh user@my_pc`, the authentication fails as the key is not used.

How to set up ssh so that `/etc/hosts` is recognised?
I know that a host name can be done in `~/.ssh/config` however is there a way to keep the host name out of that file and have it match the IP to `/etc/hosts`?

Comment: What is the error messages you see when you try this ... what actually happens ?

Comment: is the IdentityFile really in $HOME/id_rsa (like /home/youruser/id_rsa) or is it rather in $HOME/.ssh/id_rsa? (watch the '.' before ssh, it has a meaning). Also, please post the output of ssh -vv user@my_pc

Comment: When `ssh user@my_pc` is used, it attempts password authentication. If I manually enter `my_pc` into `~/.ssh/config`, it works fine though. So when only the machine IP is in `~/.ssh/config` but not the hostname, ssh looks for the hostname in `~/.ssh/config` and not the ip (by translating hostname to IP using `/etc/hosts`)

Comment: @natxoasenjo yes, the key is currently in the home folder. This is not a permanent solution and I will generate a new key inside `.ssh` once I get the hostname working.

Comment: ok. I think it fails because you are not using the host resolver, but ip addresses, then. Try creating your private 'dns zone' in your hosts file (my_pc.mylan instead of just my_pc, for instance), then use Host *.mylan , identityfile etc

Comment: @natxoasenjo Your solution works. Is there a way to get get ssh to look up the hostname IP address first and then use the IP addresses to find the keys?

Comment: @Dave, if you want to use dns, then maybe you should use a dns server ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use `/etc/hosts` file to connect `user@my-pc`. Add following lines to `~/.ssh/config`

```
Host my-pc
     Hostname 192.168.0.4
     Port 22
     User john
     IdentityFile ~/id_rsa
```

So now when you just type `ssh my-pc` it will connect to john@192.168.0.4

I have made to myself a little script to make adding new hosts as fast as possible, you may use it aswell ;)

```
#!/bin/bash
#Made by Gen Lee ^.^
#######
#Adds new host to ~/.ssh/config
ver="Ezy SSH v0.1"

#Colors:
red='\033[01;31m'
norm='\033[00m'

echo "Started $ver"
  # Questions
    echo -en "Enter ${red}host${norm}: "
    read config_host
    echo -en "Enter ${red}domain${norm}/${red}ip${norm}: "
    read config_hostname
    echo -en "Enter ${red}port${norm} (${red}22${norm}): "
    read config_port
    echo -en "Enter ${red}username${norm} (${red}root${norm}): "
    read config_user
    echo -en "Enter ${red}private key location${norm}: "
    read config_key

  # Checking information
    check_host=$(awk "/^Host $config_host$/" ~/.ssh/config)
    if [ ! $check_host ]; then
      sleep 0
    else
      echo -e "You already have following host (${red}$config_host${norm})!"
      exit 0
    fi
    if [ ! $config_port ]; then
      config_port="22"
    fi
    if [ ! $config_user ]; then
      config_user="root"
    fi
    test -f $config_key
    if [ $? -eq 1 ]; then
      echo "Private key location is invalid!"
      exit 0
    fi

  # Adding parameters to ~/.ssh/config
    echo "" >> .ssh/config
    echo "Host $config_host" >> ~/.ssh/config
    echo -e "\t Hostname $config_hostname" >> ~/.ssh/config
    echo -e "\t Port $config_port" >> ~/.ssh/config
    echo -e "\t User $config_user" >> ~/.ssh/config
    if [ ! $config_key ]; then
      sleep 0
    else
      echo -e "\t IdentityFile $config_key" >> .ssh/config
    fi
echo "All done! ^.^"
exit 0
```